# If statements in a for loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have a problem with some if statements in a for loop. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

mv = []
mb = []
mbv = []
M = []
for i in range (0,25):
    mv.append(10.1 - 2.5 * np.log10(fv[i]/1220000))
    mb.append(11.0 - 2.5 * np.log10(fb[i]/339368))
    mbv.append(mb[i]-mv[i])
    if ( 0.00 < mbv[i] < 0.05):
        M.append(1.1)
    if ( 0.05 < mbv[i] < 0.1):
        M.append(1.8)
    if ( 0.1 < mbv[i] < 0.2):
        M.append(2.2)
    else:
        M.append(0)
    print i+1, mbv[i], M[i]
```

This is what I get as a result:

```
1 0.117517744922 2.2

2 0.105291760392 2.2

3 0.0414704330434 1.1

4 0.709631736921 0

5 0.0634562921955 0

6 0.9 1.8

7 0.123732441181 0

8 0.332213182737 0

9 0.0783116509167 2.2

10 0.109696428387 0

11 0.812457966075 1.8

12 0.0796972381532 0

13 0.0933833026562 2.2

14 0.0448112197058 0

15 0.107871295045 1.8

16 0.072180255058 0

17 0.134980217798 1.8

18 0.453454266409 0

19 0.0498332192697 1.1

20 0.141914194517 0

21 0.0712870748016 2.2

22 0.622521992135 1.8

23 0.176515236738 0

24 0.607814524935 2.2

25 0.0521329729172 0

0
```

As you can see number 5 has an mbv of 0.0634, this should give an M of 1.8 but instead it gets an 0.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `elif` otherwise you will always append `0` if `mbv[i]` is not between `0.1` and `0.2`:

```
    if ( 0.00 <= mbv[i] < 0.05):
        M.append(1.1)
    elif ( 0.05 <= mbv[i] < 0.1):
        M.append(1.8)
    elif ( 0.1 <= mbv[i] < 0.2):
        M.append(2.2)
    else:
        M.append(0)
```

Your current code was resulting in multiple multiple values being added to `M` when `mbv[i]` was less than `0.1`, first `1.1` or `1.8` would be added depending on the value and then the `if ( 0.1 < mbv[i] < 0.2)` would fail and the `else` block would be entered to append `0`.

Also as noted in wagregg's answer, you should make sure the edge cases are covered by using `<=` so that if a value is exactly `0.05` or `0.1` you enter the appropriate block instead of dropping to the else.

Comment: You should include wagregg's answer as well, since the case of exactly `0.05` (for example) will get sent to the `else` still.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your < to <= to cover the case of exactly 5.

```
if ( 0.05 <= mbv[i] < 0.1):
    M.append(1.8)
```